# Selenium: Dynamic clicking of radio button beside search result

Tags: selenium, radio-button, click

I'm a month-old with Selenium and so far all I use is the IDE. Haven't had the luxury of reading on RC (although I will be after this critical project). Anyway I would like to know how I could click the radio button beside a search result w/c does not always appear on the same position. W/ my limited knowledge in Selenium and programming, best solution I can think of is **veryfyTextPresent** on the text of the result then click blindly a couple of positions beside the text using xPath (? is this even doable ?). How could I do this in a less primitive manner?

So in this scenario I would verify **Bingo!** then would like to click on the radio button beside it

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  **Bingo!**  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx

However on different searches this could look like this

O  **Bingo!**  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx  

O  xxxxxxxx

Anyway I hope I've explained my problem clearly. Thanks in advance for all your comments, suggestions and guides. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using firebug to investigate any additional distinguishing properties for the radio button. If they do exist, use them to construct a CSS identifier. If not, (and if possible), ask the developer to add properties.
Alternately, try posting the HTML tags from firebug for the radio button here..

Comment: Hi Rajat. Here's the HTML tag for the radio button. As you can see the ID is incremental depending on the number of records selected. And since records are pretty much random posting I can't quit pinpoint the exact radio button for a specific record that I'm searching for. Thanks for the tip! :)

Comment: <input type="radio" value="6" title="Select" id="OfficeMaintenance:OfficeUsersTable:6:_id64" name="OfficeMaintenance:OfficeUsersTable:selected">
<label class="x4e" for="OfficeMaintenance:OfficeUsersTable:6:_id64">Select</label>